# How to map NumPad1 to Alt+Enter?

Tags: autohotkey, remapping, keymap, nnoremap

I'm new to AutoHotKey, and I'm trying to map NumPad1 to Alt+Enter.
I have done this by right clicking on the AHK window and editing script, which is in My Documents/Autohotkey.ahk and overwriting the default script with the code above, and refreshing with F5.

Hopefully, that is also the correct way to execute the AHK change.

Additionally, I don't want my NumPad1 to be on when I start typing.

Thanks

Comment: You likely want to use `!Enter::Send {Numpad1}` (if you haven't already) and reload the script. Regarding the desire to have the Numpad1 "off" when you start typing, I am unsure what you mean by this. Numlock can be toggled with `SetNumLockState, Off` and `SetNumLockState, On` in AutoHotkey. But beyond that, you may wish to edit your question and give a clearer explanation of what exactly you wish to achieve.